# What is TLM (touch level model)

Tags: interaction-design, touch-screen, task-completion

Surely anyone need to go on something to study from , I've been searching like crazy on topic `TLM (touch level model)` and couldn't find a single piece of useful paper for free on internet/books to read from , except:

- [ACM Digital library TLM paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2638532) (paid)
- [Wikipedia TLM description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOMS#cite_ref-7) (unclear)
- [KLM Definitions in UX Stack exchange question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/78637) (incomplete def)

What is actually this `touch level model` and **what are estimated time values of TLM operators?** and is there a free study material available from where i can read details for free ? this is my first question here so if i'm in wrong forum kindly move me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in Wikipedia, TLM is an addition to GOMS family, a mutation of a sorts of KLM (keystroke level model). They both use a method of splicing user tasks into ever smaller pieces of action, all the way down to, as name suggests, keystroke level.

In KLM these actions has durations that have been obtained empirically. When you know the sequence of actions user takes you can sum up the total time the task takes to complete. Total time is only an estimate.

This process is no different in TLM. You quess the sequence of actions user takes and sum up the total time.

But because TLM is so new area of study (first papers seem to be from 2014), there are no empirically obtained times for touch actions. These are the actions listed in Wikipedia article. If you do a study that empirically defines the time estimates, please let us know.

It seems that there are two different terms that are used when talking about GOMS for touch: TLM (touch level model) and FLM (fingerstroke level model). To me they look interchangeable. Both change the name of the method of interaction from key to touch or fingerstroke. But I think it is better to stick with only term on future studies to avoid confusion.

A study on FLM (fingerstroke level model) tried to use KLM time estimations to estimate task times on touchscreen. They also empirically defined time estimates for comparing actions. Comparison is also made how these estimates hold against each other. From [Fingerstroke time estimates for touchscreen-based mobile
gaming interaction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167945715300373) by Lee et al.:

> - Tapping (T) corresponds well to the keystroking operator (K) in KLM, which is a repetitive interaction or series of interactions to perform a single task.
> - In the KLM, Pointing (P) originally refers to the time required to move a cursor from one position to the next target using the mouse. In fingerstroke movements on mobile devices, however, a finger gesture replaces a mouse so that the pointing operator inevitably includes one tapping interaction.
> - Dragging (D) measures the time required to drag or move an object on the touch screen. This is largely similar to the Drawing (D) operator in the KLM.
> - Flicking (F), an operator newly introduced in this study, measures the time used to slide a finger as quickly as possible, for as short a distance as possible. Flicking is similar to the dragging operator but differs in the release of the finger on the next target.
>
> [...]
>
> The total execution time estimation per model is 11.52 s (KLM) and 7.45 s (FLM), demonstrating that the FLM estimate underestimates the actual execution time of 7.62 s.

On [A Touch-level Model for Touch Gesture Efficiency](http://vbn.aau.dk/ws/files/198144570/MTA_14830_A_Touch_level_Model_for_Touch_Gestures.pdf) Bjerre & Pedersen use KLM to predict user task durations and compared them to tasks completed on different interaction conditions (walking, standing and sitting). They also tested whether the model predicted the results or not.

> The validation test showed that the model had an acceptable accuracy level for the predicted time without errors included.

There are also some studies suggesting that using touchscreen is somewhat faster than using mouse and keyboard. In [Age-Related Differences in Performance with
Touchscreens Compared to Traditional Mouse Input](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.409.321&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Findlater et al. discovered that:

> This study showed that the touchscreen did reduce the performance gap between older and younger adults compared to a traditional desktop setup. Across dragging, pointing, steering and crossing, older adults’ movement times decreased by 35% when moving from the desktop to the touchscreen; younger adults only saw a 16% reduction.

Comment: two unclear questions , FLM is also called TLM ? and operators mentioned above T,P,D,F are TLM operators right ?

Comment: I'm a big fan of KLM, so this is great new info for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Zulqurnainjutt I updated the answer. T,P,D and F are TLM/FLM operators derived from KLM operators.

Answer (score 2):

Author of the [original TLM paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2638532) here. I just now saw this question and wanted to respond.

The answer from @locationunknown above is pretty spot on, but I did want to comment on FLM and the status of TLM.

FLM and TLM do appear fairly similar (I haven't read the FLM paper, I'll try to get access and update this answer once I've had a chance to look at it), but we take different approaches in both adapting KLM operators and which new ones are introduced. That being said, we're both after the same thing: accurate predictions and models that can be feasibly created as part of a practical design process. It is worth noting that the FLM paper uses gaming tasks to test the model, while TLM  uses much simpler, common tasks like completing a form for its benchmarks.

We're in the process of writing up the results with benchmarks for TLM. I can't say when it will be published, but I have the data from a user study establishing estimated benchmarks. Unlike FLM, we haven't attempted to validate it, which will be the logical next step. If anyone is interested, I keep updates on my website. If you'd like to help us validate the data, please let me know! (contact information also on my website)